# How to reset a disabled 5th gen. iPod without access to a computer?

Tags: ios, password, ipod

My 5th gen. iPod is disabled because my son tried too many wrong passwords. How do I unlock it without a computer or iTunes. I just want to restore, there's nothing important on the iPod.

I've already tried holding power button with home button at the same time.

Comment: Restore implies connection to a computer. Do you mean you want to erase all content and settings on the device as opposed to restore from iTunes? If so, please edit your post for clarity.

Answer (score 2):

You need iTunes to restore an iOS device. It doesn't have to be your computer—any computer from friends/family will will do.

If Find My iPhone is enabled on the iPod and the iPod is connected to a Wi-Fi network, you can log in to iCloud and erase the iPod. Once the iPod is erased, you can sign in with your Apple ID to deactivate Activation Lock and set up the iPod as new.

Comment: Thanks I forgot to mention the ipod is in Ohio with my son, in in florida and won't be back for 2 weeks can i reset it from my ipad mini. I used my cloud and gmail to setup his ipod

Comment: @Shasta If you set up Find My iPhone with iCloud, see the alternative solution in my edited answer.

Comment: @Shasta Please edit this constraint into the main question. George is a good sport and answering your question here, but not editing your main question will likely confuse other newcomers that might not see your additional details here.

Comment: @bmike Apologies, I usually try to do this but I'm more lazy on mobile!